# TypeScript: How can I unwrap the Maybe<T> type?

Tags: typescript

How can I get the type of a variable that is wrapped in a `Maybe` type?

In this case, the implementation of `Maybe` is:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null
```

Let's assume I have a data that are typed like that:

```
type MyData = { postTitle: string } & { meta: Maybe<{ tags: Array<El> }> }
```

I need to pluck the type of El to use it elsewhere.

I'm a TS noob. I've realize that it's pretty easy to get any nested type if it is not wrapped, like `type Easy= Simple['one']['heyAnArrayHere'][number]['propOfArrayElement']`
but once Maybe comes in a way, I am done.

I think that I need a conditional type, possibly something like
`type Expand<T> = T extends Maybe<infer U> ? U : T`,
but that doesn't work at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to get in the end? `El` or `El | null`?

Comment: `El | null` is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`NonNullable<Type>` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNlAvFAEgFQLIBl4QLYQB2wA3ALABQokUGAhiAEYQA8aAfElGlAD5SEArnDjkq4aBhAAROsDpcA3lDAB7AM7A0AS2BwIALiiaATtsIBzKAF8oAMijKC8o-Satl8i+qMBBEyYMLPCc1qGUlNTQvnDqqvBcAHKqhInCcHSM+ixSsvIA2gDkznSFALrsRV7q5flCeMwmZSRAA)

```ts
type El = HTMLElement;
type Maybe<T> = T | null;
type MyData = { postTitle: string } & { meta: Maybe<{ tags: Array<El> }> }

type AlsoEl = NonNullable<MyData['meta']>['tags'][number];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a type like `Maybe<T> | undefined` to `T | undefined` you can do `myVar1 ?? undefined`.

You can learn more about the nullish coalescing operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing